# Java Many-To-Many retrieve data from join relationship

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have two beans called Course and Student with many-to-many relationship that looks like this.

Course.java

```
package ca.sheridancollege.beans;

import lombok.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@NamedQuery(name="Course.byProfID", query="from Course where prof_id=:id")
public class Course implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String courseName;
    private String department;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Professor prof;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="courseList")
    private List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public Course(String cName, String dept) {
        super();
        this.courseName = cName;
        this.department = dept;
    }


}
```

Student.Java

```
package ca.sheridancollege.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;

import lombok.*;

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@NamedQuery(name="Student.byID", query="from Student where id=:id")
public class Student implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<Course>();

    public Student(String fName,String lName, String e) {
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.lastName = lName;
        this.email = e;

    }


}
```

I have to assign some courses to the student which i do through this dao method.

```
public void assignCourse(int cid, int sid) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Student s = (Student) session.get(Student.class, sid);
    Course c = (Course) session.get(Course.class, cid);

    s.getCourseList().add(c);
    c.getStudentList().add(s);




    session.getTransaction().commit(); 
    session.close();



}
```

This method results in a joined table with the correct data called student_course. studentList_id = student's id and courseList_id = course's id that i assigned.

```
select * from student_course;
+----------------+---------------+
| studentList_id | courseList_id |
+----------------+---------------+
|              5 |             3 |
|              6 |             4 |
+----------------+---------------+



select * from course;
+----+------------+------------+---------+
| id | courseName | department | prof_id |
+----+------------+------------+---------+
|  3 | Java101    | Technology |       1 |
|  4 | Biology    | Science    |       2 |
+----+------------+------------+---------+

select * from student;
+----+-----------------+-----------+----------+
| id | email           | firstName | lastName |
+----+-----------------+-----------+----------+
|  5 | sabeeh@mail.com | Sabeeh    | Shah     |
|  6 | td@mail.com     | test      | student  |
+----+-----------------+-----------+----------+
```

Now i am trying to get from the database the courses that each student has and display it in a jsp but i don't know how to select from a joined table which i think is not even allowed so what is the other way i can achieve this?

Comment: All you need is `student.getCourses()`. That returns the courses that a student has. If you really want to do that with a query, you need a join: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that the student object holds the courseList in its instance when i retrieve a student from the database.

Answer (score 0):

to create the junction table you want "student_course" you need to use @JoinTable with oneside of the relation , you should not use "mappedBy", what you are doing is creating two separate relations

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable
private List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
```